# How do you inspect devtools.html in a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Working on an extension that use the new experimental devtools apis. How do you debug your devtools.html file with the web inspector?

Comment: Is devtools.html listed under the the extension toggle on chrome://extensions when you have a web inspector panel open?

Comment: I don't know if you can than.

Comment: @rob-w how does a question asked in '12 get marked as a duplicate of a question asked in '13?

Comment: @SpencerCarnage Purely looking at the timestamps, the other way around would indeed be more logical, but I believe that the answer in the '13 question would be more useful to future visitors. The answers in this question are not really convenient. Actually, they do not answer the question at all. The accepted answer is about getting involved with the development of the Chrome developer tools (NOT a devtools extension), and the other answer cannot be used to debug devtools extensions because the devtools APIs are only available to devtools pages, not options pages.

Comment: @rob-w I understand. And yes, the answers ultimately aren't very helpful but at the time they were the best I could get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this devtools help page](http://www.chromium.org/devtools) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You might also look at listing the HTML file as an `options_page` in your manifest.

See [this blog post](http://codemadesimple.wordpress.com/2012/11/15/debug-chrome-dev-tools-panel/) for more details.